# cyclotomic integers vs. algebraic integers

Tags: number-theory

I started reading [this document](https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Lee.pdf) where I found this definition:

> Definition 1.3. Cyclotomic integers are the elements of
>   $\mathcal{O}_K$ = $\Bbb{Z}$[α], the  ring of integers of the
>   cyclotomic field $\Bbb{Q}$(α).

To me everything is fine before the comma, but to conclude that the ring of integers of the cyclotomic field $\Bbb{Q}$(α) is effectively $\Bbb{Z}$[α] doesn't seem to be straightforward to me. Since $\alpha$ is clearly an algebraic integer every "cyclotomic integer"(as defined here) is also an algebraic integer, but the reverse statement doesn't seem evident to me.

Googling a bit further I found following [paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1706/1706.05390.pdf) devoted entirely to this problem. The proof is far from simple and involves local rings. I wonder if there is a more direct proof not involving local rings.

Comment: [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17289/quick-proof-of-the-fact-that-the-ring-of-integers-of-q-zeta-n-is-z-zeta-n) is relevant

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544264/the-ring-of-integers-in-mathbbq-zeta-is-mathbbz-zeta) here, and Milne's lecture notes. The proof there is easier, I think.

Comment: Proposition 10.2 in Chapter 1 of Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory doesn't use local rings.